# How to read a file in order to check if username has already been created

Tags: java

So I am creating a program called RegisterandLogin, which basically you have to enter a username, password and re-enter-password in order to create a new account. 
Validation of users and passwords can be done using:

1.A user name you typed in during registration can not be the same as any 
of the 5 names in username.txt.

2.Also the user name has to be between 5 and 8 characters without any numbers (i.e., the user name can be only [A-Z] or [a-z] but not any digits like [0-9]).

3.A password is also between 5 and 8 characters, with numbers allowed (so 12345 and abcde are both valid passwords).

4.The retyped password must be the same as password, otherwise, an error message is output after hitting the Register button.

When a user name passes the 5 to 8 characters validity check, user name does not exist
in username.txt, and Password passes the validity check, the new user name is added
to username.txt.

So I already created the username.txt with five names. However, the problem I have is I am not sure how to read the username.txt file so it can check whether the username has been used or not.

Code here, little long , any help will be appreciate.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RegisterandLogin extends JFrame  {


// variables for Sign up screen
private JPanel suP; 
private JLabel suName, suPW, suRetypePW;
private JTextField suNameText, suPWText, suRetypePWText;
private JButton suButton; 
public RegisterandLogin ()
    { 
    super ("Register and Login");
    signupScreen();

}

public void signupScreen () {
    suP = new JPanel ();
    // suP.setSize(50, 60);
    setLayout (new FlowLayout());
    setContentPane (suP);
    suName = new JLabel ("Name");
    suNameText = new JTextField (10);
    suPW = new JLabel ("Password");
    suPWText = new JTextField (10);
    suRetypePW = new JLabel ("Retype Password");
    suRetypePWText = new JTextField (10);
    suButton = new JButton ("Register");
    suP.add (suName);
    suP.add(suNameText);
    suP.add(suPW);
    suP.add (suPWText);
    suP.add (suRetypePW);
    suP.add (suRetypePWText);
    suP.add(suButton);
    suP.setVisible(true);
    ButtonHandler handlersu = new ButtonHandler();
    suButton.addActionListener(handlersu);
}

public void validatebyarray() {

    String[] read1=null;
            String[] read=null;
    read1=files(read);

    int minL = 5, maxL = 8;
    String stName = suNameText.getText();//username
    String stPW = suPWText.getText();//password
    String stRePW = suRetypePWText.getText();//retype password


    /******************************************************
     *  Validate user name                                   *
     ******************************************************/

    if(stName.length()< minL || stName.length() > maxL )  // Check username length
        System.out.println ("User name must be between 5 and 8");
    else 
    {
            //check invalid characters in username
        for (int i = 0 ; i < stName.length(); i ++)  // Check for invalid character
            if (!
               ((stName.charAt (i)>= 'A' && stName.charAt (i) <= 'Z') ||
               (stName.charAt (i)>= 'a' && stName.charAt (i) <= 'z')))
            {
                    System.out.println ("Username contains invalid character"); 
                    break;
            }

        // Match the names in the array (file or database)
        // Note the logic below works but is NOT secure since it discloses
        // information about user names.
        boolean uNfound = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            if (read1[j].equals(stName))
            {
                System.out.println ("User name " + read1[j] + " already exits");
                uNfound = true;
                break;
            }
        //if    (!uNfound)
        //  System.out.println ("User name " + stName + "  created");                       
    }
    System.out.println ("After UN");
    /******************************************************
     *  Validate password                                *
     ******************************************************/


    if(stPW.length()< minL || stPW.length() > maxL )  // Check username length
        System.out.println ("Password must be between 5 and 8");
    else 
    {
            //check invalid characters in username
        for (int i = 0 ; i < stPW.length(); i ++)  // Check for invalid character
            if (!
               ((stPW.charAt (i)>= '0' && stPW.charAt (i) <= '9') ||
                       (stPW.charAt (i)>= 'A' && stPW.charAt (i) <= 'Z') ||
                       (stPW.charAt (i)>= 'a' && stPW.charAt (i) <= 'z')))
            {
                    System.out.println ("Password contains invalid character"); 
                    break;
            }

        // Note stName replaced by stPW and stRePW;
        // uN[] replaced by pN[]
        boolean uNfound = false;

            if (stPW.equals(stRePW))
            {
                System.out.println ("User name " + stName + "  created");
                uNfound = true;

            }
        if  (!uNfound)
            System.out.println ("Passwords does not match");







}
    //System.out.println ("After UN again");
}





class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){

        if (event.getSource () == suButton){
            System.out.println ("SU button in register screen hit");

            validatebyarray();
        }
    }
}

public String[] files(String [] read) 
{
    try {



        BufferedReader file1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("usernames.txt"));                   
        //  Scanner fileReaderScan=new Scanner(readTextFile);

            //only want first 5 lines
            for(int count=0;count<5;count++)
            {
               read[count] = file1.readLine();  //use readLine method
           System.out.println(read[count]);
            }

       file1.close();   //close file

    }


    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("OOps");
    }
    return read;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
RegisterandLogin rl = new RegisterandLogin ();
rl.setSize(200, 300);
rl.setVisible(true);
rl.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

}
```

Comment: Sounds like homework, you should mark it as such.

Comment: Start by taking a look at [Basic IO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Comment: Say it in the question or title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below in you read method

```
public String[] files() 
    throws FileNotFoundException
{
   List<String> existingUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
   File users = new File("username.txt");
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(users);
   while (sc.hasNext()) {
       existingUsers.add(sc.nextLine());
   }
   return existingUsers.toArray(new String[existingUsers.size()]);
 }
```

Comment: Missing return statement... also your call to `toArray` will not yield any results. Also there's an unnecessary parenthesis.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison it would.Java checks automatically if size of returned collection is more than what you have specified in toArray method it would create a new array to fit that result

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. A better call however, would be `toArray(read)`, that way you don't allocate another array behind the scenes. As of now, there's no use in passing array `read` into this method.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison can you please remove your downvote :).Better approach is this existingusers.toArray(new String[existingusers.size()])

Comment: Done, good answer, +1. I've taken the liberty of improving your code. I apologize if this was too forward.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison I think better approach is this existingusers.toArray(new String[existingusers.size()]).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35179/discussion-between-algorithmist-and-william-morrison)

Comment: @Algorithmist Ok so I added that part to the code. However, when i try calling it from validatebyarray(), it states that it's wrong and the 2 fixes are:1) Add throws declaration 2)surround with try/catch

Comment: catch that FileNotFoundException either in read() or in validatebyarray() method

Comment: @user2669764 I can sense you are not using Eclipse/NetBeans?

Comment: @Algorithmist I am using Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this just using a BufferedReader as you've tried, but in the code you've written you've hardcoded the number of lines to read but the question talks about appending lines to the file.

I'd imagine you'd also want the file to contain the passwords (this is homework, in real life you never, ever store passwords) as presumably you're going to end up checking them too in some way. Given the restrictions you have to impose with regards to legal characters you can probably easily pick a separator so you can store a username and password per line in the file.

Since your use pattern is that you need to check existence efficiently a better data structure to use for the usernames would be a set, given than you'd want the passwords too, a map from username to password would be a good choice.

When using resources (such as files) it's best to close them using a finally block so that no matter what goes wrong you release your use of the resource.

So you'd end up with something like...

```
Map<String,String> loadUsersAndPasswords() {
    Map<String,String> usernameToPassword = new HashMap<String,String>();
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("usernames.txt");
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
            int splitLocation = line.indexOf(":");
            String username = line.substring(0, splitLocation);
            String password = line.substring(splitLocation + 1);
            usernameToPassword.put(username, password);
        }
    } finally {
        fr.close();
    }

    return usernameToPassword;
}
```